# How to make program dependent of another program?

Tags: windows, delphi

I have a two windows programs, ***p1*** and ***p2*** whereby ***p1*** is the ***main*** program. I want to implement a situation such that program, ***p2*** is ***dependent*** on the main program, I mean program two can't execute minus first executing the main program that is to say of someone executes program p2 without the main program it should say something like:

> p2 can't launch alone without p1 or the main app.

That's the overview of what i want to implement. Program, p1 is my own program i have developed in delphi.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: yeah p2 is not my program but my program p1 runs it to start a certain service

Comment: Does sound like an XY problem. Your program is not dependent on the other program. It's dependent on the behaviour of and the services of the other program. I'd be looking fr the behaviour or the services rather than the program.

Answer (score 0):

There's so many ways to do this that it's hard to even know where to start. You could use a mutex, pipe, shared memory, or any other IPC -- either to communicate or just check if it's been created. You could spawn app2 from app1 and validate parent process. If using a backend server you could send two requests and the server could validate if app1 was opened first.

Assuming that you own app1 but not app2, your simplest option would be using a kernel driver. Add a process notify routine and detect when both app1 and app2 are started, caching them. If app2 starts but app1 hasn't then terminate app2 from kernel land, otherwise let it run. You could also detect when app1 closes and terminate app2 at the same time if you want.

Comment: yeah I read about using kernel driver, it seemed to be what i want but failed to implement it. May be help me with a hint on it, thanks

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that writing a kernel driver is not an easy thing to do.

Comment: Can't just import some dll files like kernel32.dll and it performs whatever I need

Comment: No, it's not that simple: a kernel driver isn't an application that calls functions from kernel32.dll. (If so, all Windows applications would be "kernel drivers".)

Comment: Well, theoretically you might hook function like `CreateProcess`, but it's not as clean as having a kernel driver.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with a mutex:

```
MutexHandle := CreateMutex(NIL, TRUE, PChar('Unique String'));
AppExists   := GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS;
```

Basically, AppExists will be either true or false if the mutex was created by any process.

Comment: But the OP says p2 is not his program, so how would he get that ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS error?

Comment: If you have source to p1, then have it create the Mutex.  If you don't have source to p2, then you could create alternate p2 that tried to create the Mutex and then it executes the real p2 only if ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS.